# Changed entity found with old values in an integration test

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have the following repository:

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, String> {    
    Optional<User> findUserByUniqueName(String uniqueName);
}
```

In an integration test, first, I change the uniqueName field of a user entity and save it to database. then I call an endpoint with mockMvc and add the oldUniqueName to the headers of the request.

```
@Test
@Transactional
void test() {
User user =
    userRepository.findUserByUniqueName("oldUniqueName").orElse(null);

    assertThat(user).isNotNull();

    user.setUniqueName("newUniqueName");
    userRepository.saveAndFlush(user);

    headers = ... // adding oldUniqueName to the headers 

    mockMvc
        .perform(get(endpointUrl).headers(headers))
        .andExpect(status().isUnauthorized());

}
```

The request is then intercepted by a custom security filter to do some modifications in the security context. in this filter I extract the UniqueName from the request header and try to find the corresponding user in database:

```
@Override
@Transactional
protected void doFilterInternal(
      HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
      throws ServletException, IOException {

    String oldUniqueName = extractUniqueNameFromRequest(request);
    try {
        User user = userRepository.findUserByUniqueName(oldUniqueName).orElseThrow(new Exception());
        // update security context
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        // handle exception     
    }
}
```

I am expecting that the call to the repository with the oldUniqueName returns an empty Optional and therefore an exception is thrown. However, something strange happens. Although I am querying the database with a non existing uniqueName (oldUniqueName), the User Entity is found but it's uniqueName field has the value "newUniqueName". I guess it has something to do with transactions or maybe cache but can't figure it out. Does anybody know what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure, but it looks like the mock mvc request runs in it's own thread and therefore transaction. Since you didn't commit the transaction of your integration test, mock mvc still sees the old data.

If this assumption is true you should be able to fix it by putting the first part of your integration test in a separate transaction.
You can do this by removing the `@Transactional` annotation and use [`TransactionTemplate`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionTemplate.html) instead.